# How do I show a ProgressBar spinner when music is playing?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I created a Fart SoundBoard for my application. I am very new to developing and this is my first app. I have a bunch of buttons that play sound when clicked using the onClick button_sound.start method. How to a show a spinning progressbar only when my sound is playing via xml? Here is my code:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@raw/nuke" 
    android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Click a button to play a fart!"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="24dp" />
<SeekBar 
    android:id="@+id/sbVolume1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ranfart"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Random Fart"
    android:textColor="#0B0B61"
    android:textSize="21dp" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >    
<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fart 1"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:textSize="21dp"
    android:id="@+id/fart1"
    android:textColor="#0B0B61"/>
<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fart 2"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:textSize="21dp"
    android:id="@+id/fart2"
    android:textColor="#0B0B61"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How do I made a spinning progress loader only during sound playing?
And also how do I make the spinning progressBar ONTOP of my button? (not above, not below, but ONTOP ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting a ProgressBar or SeekBar? It sounds like you want a ProgressBar, but you're including a SeekBar in your XML. At any rate, you should read through [this example on merging two layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html). It will help you out a lot with displaying one thing on top of another. As for showing the ProgrssBar only while you are playing a sound, it would help everyone out if you let us see some of the code you're using. There are different ways to play sounds and therefore different ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: I am wanting a Progressbar. The seekbar is for my volume that I already have set up. I just need to know how to get the progressbar spinning only when music is playing. I am not on my compjter right now so i cant show u code but my java looks something like this:                                 fart1.setonClickListener(new view.onclicklistener).....bla bla..... and the i have Fart1.start();            (I have Fart1 set to a sound earlier in the java)